# Reference dynamic assembly from Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

If I dynamically compile and load an assembly (a view model in this case) in an MVC controller, how can I reference that assembly in the Razor view? I cannot use a model type of dynamic because I use lambda expressions. If I create a dll, write it to the bin folder, then load it, everything works. But this causes the AppDomain to recycle.

I realize that this approach could be a very bad idea in some cases. This is for permitting a preview function of auto-generated code and views. Load would not be a concern. I just don't want every request to restart the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the .cshtml files into a separate project that is not compiled with the controller and model code. Since .cshtml files get compiled individually and on-the-fly, that would avoid a recompile when the target assembly is recompiled. However, it would also introduce its own pain points.

Another option would be to use `dynamic`, or other not-strongly-typed approaches, and recognize that this means you can't use lambda expressions or other strongly-typed constructs. Most of the helpers that require lambdas also have versions that take simple strings, and where necessary it's still possible to  manually construct expression trees, though it requires more code.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the recompilation of the view that I'm trying to avoid. I want to prevent the AppDomain of the MVC application from recycling. This happens because I have to write my dynamic assembly to the bin folder in order for the view to be able to reference it's types.

Comment: @CuriousLayman: So views can't use types that don't reside in the bin folder of the web project at runtime? I guess that makes sense. You learn something new every day. :-)

Comment: In the end we just decided to go with dynamic view models for the preview function. I was trying to avoid it, but there doesn't seem to be an acceptable way to pull it off.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Good luck!